# Device motion updates in background

Tags: ios, swift, device, background-process, core-motion

I am trying to get device motion updates on an iPhone or iPad in the background using `CMMotionManager`. I have reviewed all previous posts on this topic and thought that I had code that would work.  My app also uses background audio, and this works properly in the foreground and  background. In `Info.plist`, I have background audio and background location updates enabled.

For testing purposes, I have declared `"var motionManager = CMMotionManager()"` in AppDelegate, and included the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.10
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler: {
        data, error in

        let accelerationVector = sqrt(pow(data!.userAcceleration.x, 2) + pow(data!.userAcceleration.y, 2) + pow(data!.userAcceleration.z, 2))
        print("\(accelerationVector)")
    })
```

When I run the app on my device, the code executes in the foreground as expected, but when I press the home button, I get about 10 more readings before it stops. When I tap on the app icon, the readings start again. I have also placed breakpoints on the code in the handler, and get similar results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I figured out the problem. I was using [mpmusicplayercontroller](/questions/tagged/mpmusicplayercontroller) to play background audio. This will play the audio in the background, but this does not keep my app running in the background. When I switched to using [avplayer](/questions/tagged/avplayer) to play audio, the app runs in the background including the device motion updates.

Answer (score 2):

**Do NOT trust the `NSLog` or other similar log output**

I used to meet this problem. I want collect the motion data in background and I made a demo about this. I found I can get all the data and log when my app in active, but the xCode log console output nothing when the application in background.

I used to think the problem is the CoreMotion data can only be collected in foreground, but I am wrong. All the callbacks still working when application enter background, **Just the `NSLog` stop telling me the data**.

If you don't believe, just collect all the data into a `NSMutableArray` or other collections, then check the data collected when app in background. 
e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrAltimeters;

...

[self.altimeter startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:self.operationQueue withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData * _Nullable altitudeData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            [self.arrAltimeters addObject:altitudeData];
            NSLog(@"Altimate data count = %ld", self.arrAltimeters.count);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have declared the motion manager in ViewDidlLoad

```
CMMotionManager              *motionManager;
/*--Initialising Motion Manager--*/
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0;
```

As whenever the app goes in background the motionManager stop providing callbacks in this case , You need to restart the motionmanager when the app goes in background or in foreground.To do this we need to follow the process below:

```
1) we first need to Register for the app transition notification :

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];


2)Notification callback functions, in which you will restart the motion manager
```

-(void)appDidEnterBackground{

```
    [self restartMotionUpdates];
}

-(void)appDidBecomeActive{
    [self restartMotionUpdates];
}


3)This function which will restart the motion manager 

-(void)restartMotionUpdates{
[motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"x=%f y=%f z=%f",fabs(motion.userAcceleration.x),fabs(motion.userAcceleration.y),fabs(motion.userAcceleration.z));
   }];
}
```